SONiC Basic Build Error with make configure
I have a Ubuntu-20.04 and latest repo branch set to master #c2055abbc
While the make init runs successfully, the make configure breaks.
The make configure PLATFORM=vs breaks -
mv: cannot move '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.sources' to '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.sources.back': Permission denied
These are owned by root:root, wonder why the script is attempting this with user permissions?
What am I doing wrong here?
TIA,
-Sg
I tried adding the user to the root group, but it does not help.

I added $SUDO to avoid this issue.
You can:
vi ./src/sonic-build-hooks/scripts/buildinfo_base.sh  

and add $SUDO to line 127 like below:
$SUDO mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.sources /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.sources.back

